# Switch between two views in Profile page with Angular 13

Tags: angular

I am working on a project with angular 13. In Profile Page I have two view. one when user has logged in own account and could edit own info with edit-btn, and other when e.g. other user can only "see" my profile. How can I implement this? I currently do not need a backend function, because that makes other colleague. I just need to be implemented reasonably in Angular and works. I don't know how to implement this and in 3 days we have to deliver the project. Would be grateful if one helps me.

View 1:

[image]

View 2:

[image]

profile.component.html:

```
<!--------------------- Linke Container ------------------------>
  <mat-card class="profileInfo">
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title>Profile Info</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
      
    <div class="Profile-Bearbeiten">
        
        <form class="formInfo" >
    
            <mat-label class="label" >Benutzername:</mat-label>
            <input matInput  class="formInfoInput" type="text">
    
    
            <mat-label class="label">Email Adresse:</mat-label>
            <input matInput  class="formInfoInput" type="text">
    
    
            <mat-label class="label">Password:</mat-label>
            <input matInput  class="formInfoInput" type="password">
        </form>
    </div>
      
        <button
          mat-stroked-button color="primary"
          type="submit"
          class="bearbeitenBtn">bearbeiten</button>

    <div class="Profile-Show">

        <form class="formInfo" >

            <mat-label class="label" >Benutzername:</mat-label>
            <mat-labe class="profileShowLabel">[Benutzername]</mat-labe>


            <mat-label class="label">Email Adresse:</mat-label>
            <mat-labe class="profileShowLabel">[Email]</mat-labe>


        </form>
        
    </div>
      
  </mat-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngIf with a flag like isAuthorized. If it's set to true, you can show the first view, else the second one. Something like this;

```
<!--------------------- Linke Container ------------------------>
  <mat-card class="profileInfo">
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title>Profile Info</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
      
    <div *ngIf="isAuthorized; else otherView"
class="Profile-Bearbeiten">
        
        <form class="formInfo" >
    
            <mat-label class="label" >Benutzername:</mat-label>
            <input matInput  class="formInfoInput" type="text">
    
    
            <mat-label class="label">Email Adresse:</mat-label>
            <input matInput  class="formInfoInput" type="text">
    
    
            <mat-label class="label">Password:</mat-label>
            <input matInput  class="formInfoInput" type="password">
        </form>
    </div>
      
        <button
          mat-stroked-button color="primary"
          type="submit"
          class="bearbeitenBtn">bearbeiten</button>

    <div class="Profile-Show">

        <form class="formInfo" >

            <mat-label class="label" >Benutzername:</mat-label>
            <mat-labe class="profileShowLabel">[Benutzername]</mat-labe>


            <mat-label class="label">Email Adresse:</mat-label>
            <mat-labe class="profileShowLabel">[Email]</mat-labe>


        </form>
        
    </div>
<ng-template #otherView>
<!-- Your view here -->
</ng-template>
      
  </mat-card>
```

Comment: Can i do that with a button? Also if if clicked of "Switch-btn" then this funktion works. can i do that?

Comment: Of course you can do button something like;
<button (click)="buttonClick()>
and in your function
this.isAuthorized = !this.authorized